# Getting blank value when trying to get the value of a FormControl object

Tags: angular

I'm trying to get the `value` of a `FormControl` object but I get blank ouput.

I'm expecting the value `991` calling this line:

`console.log(this.createForm.get('nid_customer').value)`

but I don't get anything, just blank.

This below is the output of `console.log(this.createForm.get('nid_customer')`:

Angular 15.

[image]

Comment: is it disabled ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler What do you mean?

Comment: A FormControl that is disabled won't return its value.